Reduction of periodic boundary conditions to Dirichlet boundary conditions
Let us consider the following heat equation with periodic boundary conditions, which is nothing but the problem on the flat torus:
$$ \partial_t u(x,t) - \partial_x^2 u(x,t) = f(x,t),(x,t) \in [0,1] \times [0,T],$$
$$u(x,0) = u_0(x),$$
$$u(0,t) = u(1,t),$$
$$\partial_x u(0,t) = \partial_x u(1,t).$$
(We assume that the initial datum and the source term are compatible with the boundary conditions and sufficiently smooth.)
It is quite difficult, if not impossible, to find existence/uniqueness results for general parabolic PDEs with periodic boundary conditions in the literature.
So is there a possibility to reduce the problem with periodic boundary conditions to a problem with Dirichlet boundary conditions? Then I could use standard results for Dirichlet conditions. For example by introducing an auxiliary function or by a subtle transformation?
Would be grateful for help and ideas!

I'm not sure what you mean by 'It is quite difficult, if not impossible, to find existence/uniqueness results for general parabolic PDEs with periodic boundary conditions in the literature.'; you can find the solution to the PDE you gave above in section 2.7.3 here. I'm pretty sure you can show uniqueness using standard energy arguments.

@Matthew Cassell Thanks. The example in the OP was just for concreteness. Actually I need an existence/uniqueness result for the PDE
$\partial_t u(x,t) - a \cdot \partial_x^2 u(x,t) + g(x,t) \cdot u(x,t)= f(x,t)$ on the one-dimensional Torus. Unfortunately I can't find any literature reference. Would be glad if you would know some?
(I meant that most textbooks I know, e.g. Evans, Rogers/ Renardy, Wu/Jin, focus on Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions but not on periodic boundary cond.)
